# How can I query the ip-address of a DDS Publisher when using OpenSplice DDSI2

Tags: data-distribution-service, opensplice

I am using OpenSplice to publish data and to subscribe to data.

On the subscribe side I want to be able to query the ip-address of the publisher.

The primary reason for wanting to do this is that I need to copy very large files from the publisher and I don't need to share the files via DDS and I may need to terminate/'rate limit' the copy if bandwidth becomes constrained/limited.

The copying is one off so I can use rsync and ssh, but to achieve this I need the ip-address of the publisher. I could iterate over the network interfaces on the publisher side, however there is likly to be more that one valid network interface.

I've spent quite sometime trying to find a way to query the necessary information from the dds::sub::DataReader (or associated classes) but my search skills have failed me and was wondering if it was at all possible before I fallback to something less elegant.

There is a related RTI question/answer: [Get IP Address of DataWriter/Publisher on RTI DDS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610680/get-ip-address-of-datawriter-publisher-on-rti-dds)

Comment: I looked for quite sometime through the code and could not find anything exposed via the API that would allow me to find the ip-address of the publisher. I have therefore gone with publishing all network interface adresses, except loopback, to subscribers. The subscribers then check each address to see if it is accessible.